# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ')' (at

Tags: angular, angular-cli

When I build the project with the `ng build --configuration=production` command, sometimes and for some systems, an error is displayed. which may disappear by clearing the cache, but it may still be displayed.

I used Angular 12

[image]

[image]

```
<html lang="fa" class="h-100">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Project</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
  <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
  <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>

<body class="h-100 fixed-menu">
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I have faced this issue before but sadly I could not fix that.

Answer (score 0):

I got to know, it is something related to Hashing added to the map file during the production build.

**So I ran this which resolved this issue:**

```
ng build --aot --prod --output-hashing none
```

After that, it created the bundle without any Hashing using Ahead Of Time compilation which resolved this issue at all places.

Comment: The output files look like this: `5.js`,`20.js`, `common.js`, `...`
This will cause the browser to cache the files in the next builds and not show the new files.